# Using df.divide on preceding column total

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df:

```
count      0       1    2     3      4
cohort                  
2020-10   46.0   18.0   10.0 3.0    NaN
2020-11   290.0  113.0  40.0 13.0   NaN
2020-12   370.0  176.0  61.0 6.0    1.0
2021-01   561.0  240.0  66.0 4.0    1.0
2021-02   575.0  280.0  80.0 5.0    NaN
2021-03   671.0  274.0  73.0 3.0    1.0
2021-04   1028.0 438.0  56.0 1.0    NaN
2021-05   1191.0 488.0  10.0 2.0    NaN
2021-06   1320.0 607.0  12.0 1.0    NaN
2021-07   1309.0 495.0  9.0  1.0    NaN
2021-08   921.0  209.0  NaN  NaN    NaN
2021-09   653.0   7.0   NaN  NaN    NaN
2021-10   633.0   3.0   NaN  NaN    NaN
2021-11   708.0   5.0   1.0  NaN    NaN
2021-12   390.0   4.0   NaN  NaN    NaN
```

I am doing a cohort analysis and I want  create two charts. One where each step is divided by the total cohort size, and one where it's divided by the previous column's size.

The first chart I was able to achieve by using

`df1 = df.divide(df.iloc[:,0], axis = 0)`

Which results:

```
count   0     1             2           3        4
cohort                  
2020-10 1.0  0.391304   0.217391    0.065217    NaN
2020-11 1.0  0.389655   0.137931    0.044828    NaN
2020-12 1.0  0.475676   0.164865    0.016216    NaN
2021-01 1.0  0.427807   0.117647    NaN         NaN
2021-02 1.0  0.486957   0.139130    NaN         NaN
2021-03 1.0  0.408346   0.108793    NaN         NaN
2021-04 1.0  0.426070   0.054475    NaN         NaN
2021-05 1.0  0.409740   NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-06 1.0  0.459848   NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-07 1.0  0.378151   NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-08 1.0  0.226927   NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-09 1.0  NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-10 1.0  NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-11 1.0  NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
2021-12 1.0  NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
```

However, now I want a similar table which instead of dividing by the `0` index throughout the entire df, I want every column to divide by the size of the previous column

Resulting Df portion (roughly):

```
count   0     1             2           3        4
cohort                  
2020-10 1.0  0.391304   0.555555    0.30        NaN
2020-11 1.0  0.389655   0.354       0.32        NaN
```

Constructor:

```
dictionary = {0: {Period('2020-10', 'M'): 46.0,
  Period('2020-11', 'M'): 290.0,
  Period('2020-12', 'M'): 370.0,
  Period('2021-01', 'M'): 561.0,
  Period('2021-02', 'M'): 575.0,
  Period('2021-03', 'M'): 671.0,
  Period('2021-04', 'M'): 1028.0,
  Period('2021-05', 'M'): 1191.0,
  Period('2021-06', 'M'): 1320.0,
  Period('2021-07', 'M'): 1309.0,
  Period('2021-08', 'M'): 921.0,
  Period('2021-09', 'M'): 653.0,
  Period('2021-10', 'M'): 633.0,
  Period('2021-11', 'M'): 708.0,
  Period('2021-12', 'M'): 390.0},
 1: {Period('2020-10', 'M'): 18.0,
  Period('2020-11', 'M'): 113.0,
  Period('2020-12', 'M'): 176.0,
  Period('2021-01', 'M'): 240.0,
  Period('2021-02', 'M'): 280.0,
  Period('2021-03', 'M'): 274.0,
  Period('2021-04', 'M'): 438.0,
  Period('2021-05', 'M'): 488.0,
  Period('2021-06', 'M'): 607.0,
  Period('2021-07', 'M'): 495.0,
  Period('2021-08', 'M'): 209.0,
  Period('2021-09', 'M'): 7.0,
  Period('2021-10', 'M'): 3.0,
  Period('2021-11', 'M'): 5.0,
  Period('2021-12', 'M'): 4.0},
 2: {Period('2020-10', 'M'): 10.0,
  Period('2020-11', 'M'): 40.0,
  Period('2020-12', 'M'): 61.0,
  Period('2021-01', 'M'): 66.0,
  Period('2021-02', 'M'): 80.0,
  Period('2021-03', 'M'): 73.0,
  Period('2021-04', 'M'): 56.0,
  Period('2021-05', 'M'): 10.0,
  Period('2021-06', 'M'): 12.0,
  Period('2021-07', 'M'): 9.0,
  Period('2021-08', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-09', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-10', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-11', 'M'): 1.0,
  Period('2021-12', 'M'): nan},
 3: {Period('2020-10', 'M'): 3.0,
  Period('2020-11', 'M'): 13.0,
  Period('2020-12', 'M'): 6.0,
  Period('2021-01', 'M'): 4.0,
  Period('2021-02', 'M'): 5.0,
  Period('2021-03', 'M'): 3.0,
  Period('2021-04', 'M'): 1.0,
  Period('2021-05', 'M'): 2.0,
  Period('2021-06', 'M'): 1.0,
  Period('2021-07', 'M'): 1.0,
  Period('2021-08', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-09', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-10', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-11', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-12', 'M'): nan},
 4: {Period('2020-10', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2020-11', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2020-12', 'M'): 1.0,
  Period('2021-01', 'M'): 1.0,
  Period('2021-02', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-03', 'M'): 1.0,
  Period('2021-04', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-05', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-06', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-07', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-08', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-09', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-10', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-11', 'M'): nan,
  Period('2021-12', 'M'): nan}}
```

Comment: Kindly share the expected output dataframe

Comment: I have to calculate it manually so ill add it soon, but the math should check out

Comment: @sammywemmy, there I created a small snippet of what it should be (not accounting for rounding)

Comment: ``df.div(df.shift(axis=1))``? You can fill the first column with 1, to match your output -> ``df.div(df.shift(axis=1)).fillna({0:1})``